# No target variable in my data

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, machine-learning-model, data-science-model, data-analysis

I have a list of transactions of bus route from place to place, I don't have any target variable here. I was asked to give meaningful insights from the data, what can I do here?

I cleaned the data, replaced missing values in distance, price. Doing only descriptive analytics, what predictive analytics can we give here?

Here is a sample of my data,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have enough room in the comments so I'm responding here.

I don't think you'll provide anything useful if you build models to predict any of the columns in your sample.

However, your descriptive analytics should offer a lot of insight, for example, you can say which type of vehicle is more popular for a certain purpose in a certain city and so much more. So while you don't actually predict anything, you're showing the likelihood that something happens for a specific purpose. This itself is useful for business decisions.

Comment: Thank you, I have a plan to bind transactions by week and do time series analysis. So I cannot do predictions with this available data, what more details are required to do predictive analytics on this.

Comment: It's hard to speculate on what else is needed. I'd suggest getting as much as you can and then figure out if there is any way you can make a user's decision for them. If you know certain things about a user, can you predict something to expedite their process? For example, if you know why a user is in a certain city, maybe you can automatically give them the departure times and cost of the vehicles that service their purpose in that city. It all depends on the data available.

Comment: No its not about user, they have to book a whole bus. If they are going out with family on any occasion they can book small cars also, I will look into it bro Thanks.